# Sencha Touch app sluggish after adding background image

Tags: css, extjs, sencha-touch-2, sencha-touch-2.1

I have a Sencha Touch 2 app that has a tab panel with 3 tabs and slide animation enabled.

I have added a background image for all components using this css -

```
.x-layout-card-item {
background-image: <image>
}
```

After adding the image, the app is very sluggish.

eg: When I switch tabs, it takes up to 2 seconds and it changes tab without slide animation.

As soon as i remove the background-image, the app is much faster in rendering the views. Now when i switch tab, it immediately changes tab WITH slide animation.

So what is the best way to add a background-image to the app for all screens in the app without impacting the performance?

(TESTED on Android - Nexus 5)

Comment: How large is the image? Eg 30kb.

Comment: The image size is 138kb. I tried to minimize it down to 20kb. Still the issue was the same.

Comment: Some of the other elements have background transparent so that the image can be seen. Does transparency cause any lag?

Comment: Similar Issue reported here - 
http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?178112-background-image-performance-issues

Comment: May be it's because of loading a image at the time of instance creation.You can do 1 thing, put that image ref in index.html, so it'll load before application starts. And than try your code.